# Nuget Newby question

Tags: nuget

I installed NuGet, but when I go to Add Library Package Reference, there are no packages showing up.  How do I tell it to look online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest version of NuGet installed and make sure that the official source is http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206669

Comment: I did that and it worked.  I do not like that 206669 is such a "magic" number though.  What the heck does it mean, and why will it not change arbitrarily, and if it does change, how would anyone know?   Also - I could download some packages but not others (could get AutoMapper but not RestSharp).  The failed ones simply stated "operation timeout".  Not very helpful :(

Comment: It's a fwlink. The whole point is that it doesn't change. The url that it points to changes...