# Nuget Feed Address

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins, nuget

somehow my VS does point to the wrong feed ... what is the feed address ... not easy to find

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In visual studio, go to Tools menu -> library package manager -> package manager settings.

Earlier Visual Studio configuration for NuGet 1.2 points at
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206669

This link resolves to
http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/ (don't use this, just for verification)

**Update** In Visual Studio 2013, I get https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ (as "Available package sources") and https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/ (as "Machine-wide package sources")

(Thanks @mheyman)

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg ... there was a typo in the address I entered

Comment: there was a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215941/nuget-newby-question ... Just for future reference

Comment: I get [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/) (as "Available package sources") and [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/) (as "Machine-wide package sources")

Comment: Default install his it broken... Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

As of VS2015 (SP2?) the default and only feed available appears to be the MS-Curated "Microsoft and .NET" one - https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/, which is missing a LOT of packages.

For VS2015 you can resolve this by opening as Admin, going to:

1. Tools > Options
2. NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources
3. Click
   the green "add" icon, and add the following feed:

https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Comment: Thanks. For VS2015 only https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json, not https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue with a fresh install of **Visual Studio 2019 Preview**...

To fix it, on the toolbar click  **Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings**

Then on the Options window expand the **NuGet Package Manager** tree option

Click on **Package sources**

Click the PLUS **+** icon to add a new package source (the feed url)

[image: NuGet Package Manager Options]

In the **Name** textbox give the package source a suitable name.

In the **Source** textbox, type the URL: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Click **Update** button > then **OK** button

I reloaded the Nuget Package Manager window and it brought up the full list of packages.

[image: Manage NuGet Packages For Solution]